# WinForms - Dynamically Add Multiline Textboxes to Panel with Horizontal Scrollbars

Tags: winforms

I have been given a design that I have to reproduce in Winforms. My attempt is shown below...

[image]

At the moment I have 5 static labels and 5 static multiline text boxes to hold my lists of "items"...

But, I need to be able to cope with more than 5 columns...

Not being massively experienced in Winforms, what would be the best way to be able to add additional columns with a horizontal scrollbar to enable the user to scroll from left to right?

I was thinking that maybe a panel, with scrollbars set to Auto, and then dynamically add the titles and text boxes at calculated positions?

Is that possible? Is that the best approach?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Trev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this looks the way to do it...

this code worked as a test...

```
        int number = 0;
        int LocationX = 169;

        while (number < 10)
        {

            // create a new multiline text box
            TextBox trev = new TextBox();
            trev.Size = txtParent1.Size;
            trev.Location = new Point() { X = txtParent1.Location.X + LocationX, Y = txtParent1.Location.Y };
            trev.Name = number.ToString();

            panelSummary.Controls.Add(trev);

            number = number + 1;
            LocationX += 169;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view that includes a label and the text box and in the main view you could use a TableLayoutPanel, for every view create a new column and add the view inside the column with Dock set to Fill. This way the resizing and the scrolling is handled by the TableLayoutPanel.

[TableLayoutPanel](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v%3Dvs.110%29.aspx&ei=2PhYVI2XHsTKaOXPgugD&usg=AFQjCNGwoJSIWWJZ6GktXYNX73DUOn_IHg&sig2=zVVsW38lvkYIlnZnxEF50w&bvm=bv.78677474,d.d2s)